# Importing an Excel file to a SharePoint custom list programmatically UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, sharepoint, excel-interop, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to import the data from an Excel file into a SharePoint custom list programmatically using a Visual Studio Workflow coded in C#.

I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace and calling the Application() interface within it to provide a reference to the application so I can use it as suggested by many forums.

When I try this I receive an UnauthorizedAccessException error.

I have tried the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method from the SPSecurity class (as suggested [here](http://jasonlochan.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/unauthorizedaccessexception-and.html):)to try with system level privileges to no good effect. I should have system administrator privileges anyway since I am running this as a local development session on my laptop where the site is hosted locally.

If anyone has any ideas as to how I might get round this problem or can suggest an alternative method of importing the data from Excel to a SharePoint list it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could do this same thing in MS Access in about 5 minutes. Right click import spreadsheet to linked sharepoint table.

Comment: It needs to be done automatically as part of a workflow when the excel file is uploaded to a document library on the SharePoint site.

Comment: sorry, I thought I might help.. I just love using Access to automate pushing data / documents into SharePoint.. It works great.